# codesandbox.io Invalid SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/ seems to have an invalid SSL Cert or so my browser suggests.  As such, my companies proxy services are blocking this site.  Anyone have any info on why this is happening or who we could reach out to to get this resolved?

[image]

Comment: It is working for me. Verify certificate - maybe some is really trying to steal your secure connection.

Comment: Nobody here even knows who your company is, much less what they are doing and why. You need to talk to them.

Comment: To be clear dave-thompson-085, I was asking if anyone knew why codesandbox's cert is invalid.  Now, I'm not a network guy so it's possible my companies firewall is somehow highjacking the traffic and not allowing codesandbox's cert to validate.  I just really wanted to confirm if their cert was invalid which could tell me if it's something on my end.